# Jquery Validator is not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add validation to a dynamic input field. What I'm doing is basically hide and show a field (having both loging and register form in 1) like this:

```
<div id="RegBoxStorage" style="display: none;">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Auth", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AuthForm" }))
{
<div id="RegBox" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="LoginBox">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Password)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
<input type="submit" id="BtnAuthSub" value="Login" />
or <a id="ToggleAuth" href="#">Sign Up</a>
}
```

The script:

```
$('#AuthForm').removeData("validator");
$('#AuthForm').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(this.authForm); // error here
```

The plugin:

```
(function ($) {
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent = function (selector) {
    //use the normal unobstrusive.parse method
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector); //Error here

    //get the relevant form
    var form = $(selector).first().closest('form');

    //get the collections of unobstrusive validators, and jquery validators
    //and compare the two
    var unobtrusiveValidation = form.data('unobtrusiveValidation');
    var validator = form.validate();

    $.each(unobtrusiveValidation.options.rules, function (elname, elrules) {
      if (validator.settings.rules[elname] == undefined) {
        var args = {};
        $.extend(args, elrules);
        args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname];
        //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
        $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
      } else {
        $.each(elrules, function (rulename, data) {
          if (validator.settings.rules[elname][rulename] == undefined) {
            var args = {};
            args[rulename] = data;
            args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname][rulename];
            //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
            $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
})($);
```

So when a user clicks `ToggleAuth`, i move the content from `RegBoxStorage` to `RegBox` inside the form. Now I need to manually add the validation to the input. All the unobtrusive validation attributes are already on it. So from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements/5783020#5783020), i tried it and says `$.validator is undefined`.

But the other parts of the form is actually validated, showing that validation works, I have both jquery.validation and jquery.validation.unobtrusive validation referenced. What could be the problem?

I also took the plugin extension from this [blog](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/).

Comment: Can you add your javascript code?

Comment: I had the same issue, problem was MVC4 does not render the validate bundle by default in _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check few things:

- You have written extension but still in section Script use `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(this.authForm)` - make sure you use parseDynamicContent.
- Make sure you reference validation.js and validation.unobtrusive.js before the plugin code.
- Make sure your Script section is inside jQuery document.ready function and executes after the plugin.

Comment: In my case, it turns out i kept thinking i had the right script included, but in reality it was **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax** and not **jquery.validate.unobtrusive** .... took me a while before i spotted it.