# Why does form validation not work in MVC3 partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, view, partial

Anybody?  There is another question regarding this but the only answers were to code up some javascript validation, which also refuses to work on my partial view ("$ is not defined").

Anyway, I don't want to use javascript I just want simple validation for required fields that cannot be left blank, number fields that require ints, etc.

Can anyone shed some light on validation and partial views?

Comment: Could we see some code please?

Comment: Do i need to show some code? Validation in partial views appears to be a general problem with MVC3 (or even MVC2) and one that does not appear to have much of a solution other than Javascript workarounds.

Comment: @Tyler, yes you need to show some code that allows to reproduce the problem. Personally I have never had any problems with client side validation in partials in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: ok, its just a lot of code with 3 partial views. probably too much to post on here. and after looking around i was thinking it was a general problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery.validate.unobtrusive not working with dynamic injected elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you are loading those partial views using AJAX. If this is the case you will need to manually invoke the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method once you inject the new contents of the partial into the DOM as explained in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/05/unobtrusive-client-side-validation-with-dynamic-contents-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Brad Wilson also discussed this in his [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html):

> The unobtrusive client validation script automatically parses the
>   initial set of HTML for validation rules when the page has finished
>   loading. If your page dynamically adds new HTML content (perhaps
>   throught Ajax or through client-side application code), you may wish
>   to parse that new HTML for client validation on the new HTML elements.
>
> To parse new HTML, you can call the
>   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse() method, passing it a selector for
>   the HTML that you would like to be parsed. You can also call the
>   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement() function to parse a single
>   HTML element.

As far as the *$ is not defined* error you should make sure that you have included the proper scripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also make sure you are not referencing any of the Microsoft*.js scripts. They are obsolete and should no longer be used in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Of course that's only a supposition, you haven't shown any code so we cannot know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and i found that it's not possible to call $.validator.unobtrusive.parse() on the same form twice. 
When loading the form initially from the server the form is parsed automatically by the unobtrusive library. When you add an input element dynamically to the form and call $.validator.unobtrusive.parse() again, it won't work. The same goes for parseElement().

So before you call $.validator.unobtrusive.parse, remove the original validator and unobtrusive validation from the form like so:

```
success: function (html) {
                        $("#div-id").append(html);
                        var form = $("#div-id").closest("form");
                        form.removeData('validator');
                        form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#editorRows"));
                    }
```