# How do I get ModelState.AddModel Error to bind to knockout dynamically created validation spans?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, knockout.js

I have setup Knockoutjs to dynamically create an editable list of values using the following code:

```
       var requirementModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.requirementtypes = ko.observableArray(@Html.Interpret(Model.requirementtypes));
        self.requirementid = ko.observable(@Html.Interpret(Model.requirementid));
        self.AddRequirementType = function() {
            self.requirementtypes.push({
                requirementtypeid: null,
                number: "",
                requirementid: 0
            });
        };
        self.RemoveType = function(Type) {
            self.requirementtypes.remove(Type);
        };
        self.hookUpValidation = function() {
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('.dynamicData');
        };
    };
    var viewModel = new requirementModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

With html:

```
 <div class="small-box dynamicData"  data-bind="template:{ name: 'requirementType-template', foreach: requirementtypes, afterRender:$root.hookUpValidation }" ></div>
<button data-bind='click: AddType'>Add Type</button>
```

I have hooked up validation for dynamic data using the code recommended on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements).

When I post back to the server (I'm not using JSON just form post) I can do more complex validation and if something fails I can use ModelState.AddModelError("input field name", "I pity the fool that broke this"); This works perfectly with either strongly type or @Html.ValidationMessage("input field name") for non dynamic fields

However I can't find a way to hook Server Side Model Error to dynamic content.

I have the span tags that work with the client side and they work perfectly. However they aren't getting hooked into data returned after serverside validation fails and return page. Any idea how to acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: The preferred approach is to build a custom ModelBinder to bind the incoming values to your model and let the default validation mechanism to kick-in. Do you mean your models are generated on client-side and you do not have it defined on server?

Comment: Model is defined on server side. A section of the page uses knockoutjs to add items to a list. I am getting everything back perfectly via post. The dynamic data is all posted. The issue is if I raise an error server side (e.g. complex validation) and then return to the view any errors raised against dynamically created items aren't bound.

Comment: I'm thinking I am probably going to have to access modelstate and add appropriate errors to Knockout model and then use that. Just wondered if there was a more elegant way (like how I got client side validation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just finished coding this for my current work project.  I cannot post the code for propitiatory rules. Like your comment above says, there isn't an elegant way.  I will describe the steps that we took to display our error messages.

First, modify your dynamically generated html so that each has the equivalent code to MVC3 @Html.ValidationFor(...) control.  Next each dynamic control needs to have an id field that you can use to locate control to add error message to.

Steps I took were, starting after the controller receives the ajax data for validation -

1. Validate the received data model
2. Create a class to return the results that looks like this

   ```
   Class AjaxResults{
       bool success {get; set;);
       object returnedData {get; set;);
   }
   ```
3. If model validates, return `AjaxResults` with `success` = true and `returnedData` = "validated data model"
4. If models does not validate then
5. Collect all the errors into a list of  pairs.  Where key = fieldID and value = "the error message".
6. return `AjaxResults` with `success` = false and `returnedData` = "list of errors"
7. After client receives the `AjaxResults` object
8. If `success` = true, process result normally.
9. If `success` = false, iterate through list highlighting the fields with the error and displaying the error message.

In the last step, you can use the jquery validation message display the error code.  If you want to do this, then in jquery.unobtrusive.valiation.js file

1. Add code to duplicate the functionality of onError method in the file.
2. Add code to interate through the error list calling your onError method to display the messages.  Be careful here in that information is stored in the .data attribute of the Error Message span.
3. You may need to write code to clear all of these errors upon submitting the form.

This is a fairly long procedure.  But the code is easily modularized into callable routines.  We are currently using this in our production code and in practice, it becomes part of our framework code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I will look into doing it that way. Pity it is less than elegant! I wish all the validation and dynamic data played together a little nicer.

Comment: I just stumbled across this post, which it seems like provides one of the better solutions for hooking up mvc server side validation to knockoutjs. I would like to follow up on this topic and see if this worked for you, @GraemeMiller well or if you had troubles. If it worked well, I'm wondering if you could post a bit more of the code examples for this.

Comment: At first sight, I think [this](http://bojankaurin.github.io/knockout-server-side-validation/) accomplishes something like described in the above answer.