# ASP.NET MVC Unobtrusive client validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, fluentvalidation

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application I am trying to use unobtrusive client validation with Fluent Validation.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I have these two .js files that VS2010 provides when new ASP.NET MVC 4 application is created. I have also enabled client side validation on my web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

As far as I know when client validation and unobtrusive JavaScript is enabled, input fields with a client-validation rule contain the data-val="true" attribute to trigger unobtrusive client validation. And I have these field on my input fields.

For instance,

```
<input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val- 
required="error text here" id="purchasePrice" 
name="PurchasePrice" type="text" value="">

<span class="field-validation-error error" data-valmsg-for="PurchasePrice" 
data-valmsg-replace="true">'Purchase Price' must not be empty.</span>
```

However, when I submit my form, it is posted to controller and my model is checked on my controller code instead of client side.

**EDIT :**

This is my form opening tag.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, 
   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "mainForm",
         @id = "productCreateForm" }))
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you made sure that the main JQuery js file and the two you've shown there are resolved correctly?

Comment: main jQuery file is definitely resolved, I have a lof of jquery functions working correctly. I do not know whether two of them resolved or not to be honest. Those files exist and they seem available in scripts part of chrome developer tools.

Comment: Another stupid question, have you generated inputs from a model to be validated?

Comment: Can we get the code for your opening form tag too please?

Comment: Maybe, is it dynamic content? Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/5783020/989462 for dynamic content.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: unfortunately no. instead i used jQuery validate plugin for client side validation and fluent validation for server side.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the configuration for MVC?

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    // this line is required for fluent validation
    FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
}
```

You also need to configure each view model / validator:

```
[Validator(typeof(PersonValidator))]
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public PersonValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(0, 10);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(x => x.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 60);
    }
}
```

If this does not help, could you post an example of a validator that is not working correctly? Not all validation can be done client side. For example, the following validator will only work server side:

```
// when validator rules are always server side
public class ServerSideValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public ServerSideValidator() {
        When(x => x.Name == "Foo", () => {
            RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for answer but I have all of them. This is my validation code : RuleFor(product => product.Manufacturer).NotNull();

Comment: What is Manufacturer? Is that a string or a class?