# jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive client side validation only works when scripts are on view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have an **ASP.NET MVC 4 App** that uses the **jQuery.validation.js** plugin and MVC's **jQuery.validation.unobtrusive.js**. I use data annotations on my view model to validate a textbox's input to be an integer.

This (nested) view is loaded within a parent view using...

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("New"); %>
```

One the first inital page load, client side validation works. But any reloading of the nested view with an ajax call, client side validation no longer works. Why is that?

**Update**: (Code example from *webdeveloper's* solution  below)

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```

Example:

```
var saveAndUpdate = function (url) {
    var myForm = $('form', $('#TheDivThatContainsTheNewHTML'));
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: myForm.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#TheDivThatContainsTheNewHTML').html(result);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#TheDivThatContainsTheNewHTML'));          
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`But any reloading of the nested view with an ajax call, client side validation no longer works. Why is that?`

Validation applies on `document ready`, when you refreshing page you should manually init validation for your form.

Like this:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```

Same question: [jquery.validate.unobtrusive not working with dynamic injected elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements)

Comment: Thanks! I also notice that you can resolve this by explicitly adding in the script tags in the nested view, instead of relying on the scripts that are rendered by the Master page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310448/mvc4-custom-unobtrusive-validator-isnt-working here is good point to check as well