# jQuery validation plugin on a form that's generated using ajax after page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

How do I get the jQuery validation plugin to work on a form that's generated using ajax after the page loads? I have a from on my page that's returned from an ajax call, and the jquery validation plugin will not validate that form when I do like below. Any ideas on how to do this? When I submit the form, it submits the usual way, not using ajax

It's currently setup like this, where `<form id="newRequest">` is generated after a user clicks a link on the page.

However, the plugin will not validate `#newRequest`

```
$("#newRequest").validate({
    rules: {

    },
    messages: {

    },

    submitHandler: function() {
    $.ajax({

    //etc
```

Comment: You need to call the plugin initialization after the form is created

Comment: Put the call to `.validate()` in the `success:` function of the AJAX call.

Comment: @ArunPJohny How do I do that? I also did as Barmar suggested, but it still wont validate.

Comment: Then you also need to show us the `ajax()` code that generates the form.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic elements are treated differently by the jQuery validation. You need to parse the form in validation flow like this,

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#newRequest");
```

This has been answered [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105170/jquery-validation-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-only-works-when-scripts-are) as well.

Nicely [**tutorial**](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/).

Comment: Where exactly does the OP say that he was using the unobtrusive validation plugin?