# Validation of field inserted with after or append

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have a form with ASP MVC3, and the `input` fields are validated with jQuery validate plugin v1.8 (default jQuery validation with MVC3). This is working perfectly, but the problem is when I insert a new field to validate using the `after` or `append` function.

If I have this HTML:

```html
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input class="text-files" data-val="true" data-val-required="Name missing" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

It works OK, but if I insert it with `after` or `insert` function, it doesn't work:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#addName').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $newdiv = $('<label for="name">Name: </label><input class="text-files" data-val="true" data-val-required="Name missing" id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>');

        $('.names').append($newdiv);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is "doesn't work"?  However, if you dynamically add a form field, you'd use the [`rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) to apply the rules.

Comment: Doesn´t work means that the new field is not validated. About rules(add), it doesn´t work because MVC uses unobtrusive client validation. I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements

Comment: That `unobtrusive` validation is always more of a pain than it's worth.   Also, please post your actual solution below rather than just a link.  It's the best way to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The validation rules are built on elements available on DOM load. Therefore you need to use the following code to tell jQuery validate to include another field in the validation:

```
$('#addName').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $newdiv = $('<label for="name">Name: </label><input class="text-files" data-val="true" data-val-required="Name missing" id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>');
    $("#name").rules("add", "required"); // let validate know about the new field.

    $('.names').append($newdiv);
});
```

Comment: That didn´t work, but I solved with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements althought I had to parse the whole form container instead of the element: $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('form') instead of $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('#name')