# Knockout JS - How to update KO binding attributes after a page renders? - Needed for JQuery unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, unobtrusive-validation

After a page is rendered a field that was set to be required with KO to "data-value=true" is, after user input, not needed to be validated by JQuery unobtrusive validation. How can the attribute be updated to "false" so that the field will not be set to required?

I have tried unsuccessfully using  f.attr("data-val", "false"), which updates the Object itself and not attr: item.

Comment: Show some code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reparse the form.

The important lines of code are below.

```
currForm.removeData("validator");
currForm.removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(currForm);
```

The solution was found here. 
[jquery.validate.unobtrusive not working with dynamic injected elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the knockout "attr" binding. 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

You could possible pass to the attr binding a KO observable that returns true / false. You could also create a custom KO computed observable which returns true / false based on other propeties on your view model (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

If you get stuck, post a 'cut back' sample of what you're trying to achieve, including your html and viewmodel javascript.

Comment: thanks for the tip. However, turns out the solution was a little trickier than that. See the correct answer above.