# How to reset the formatted ErrorMessages of the validation attributes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-validation

I used a Custom validation attribute -`AmountShouldBeLessOrEqualAttribute`- that its validation process related to value of another property and this attribute works **successfully**.

But in the following scenario I have a problem with it:

1. Start the Application
2. Going to the Form page
3. Submit the Form (POST the form **for first time**)
4. The `ModelBinding` process cause that the value of `ErrorMessage` in the `AmountShouldBeLessOrEqual` attribute be formatted. For example:

   > In the `ViewModel` there is an `Amount` property with the above attibute
   >
   > and
   >
   > Its ErrorMessage: `Your amount should be less than {0}`
   >
   > Will be convert to:   `Your amount should be less than 23`
   >
   > Note: `23` is the value of `MaxAmount` property in the `ViewModel`
5. Now I change the `MaxAmount` to `83`
6. We go to the Form page **again** and submit the form
7. The `ModelBinding` process will be start the validation process of `AmountShouldBeLessOrEqualAttibute`. Now if I watch the value of ErrorMessage property **it is not** `Your amount should be less than {0}`, it remained as the old formatted text: `Your amount should be less than 23`. So it can not be formatted again to `Your amount should be less than 83`

**My question:**

How should I reset the formatted `ErrorMessages` to its `Non-Formatted` version each time to be formatted with new value?

In `ViewModel`:

```
[AmountShouldBeLessOrEqual(nameof(MaxAmount), ErrorMessage = "Your amount should be less than {0}")]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }

public decimal MaxAmount { get; set; }
```

`AmountShouldBeLessOrEqualAttribute`:

```
public class AmountShouldBeLessOrEqualAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _comparisonProperty;
    public AmountShouldBeLessOrEqualAttribute(string comparisonProperty)
    {
        _comparisonProperty = comparisonProperty;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString;
        var currentValue = (decimal)value;

        var comparisonValue = GetComparisonValue(_comparisonProperty, validationContext);

        if (ErrorMessage == null && ErrorMessageResourceName == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Amount is large";
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage = string.Format(ErrorMessage ?? "", comparisonValue);
        }

        return currentValue >= comparisonValue
            ? new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage)
            : ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }
    private decimal GetComparisonValue(string comparisonProperty, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(comparisonProperty);

        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not Found!");

        var comparisonValue = (decimal)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        return comparisonValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33050092/1258525

Comment: @BrianOgden, No, the problem is server side and the `Error Message` is formatted in server side after first time that the form has been submitted. When I put a `BreakPoint` in `IsValid` method I see that `MaxAmount` is filled with `83` but the formatted message dose not let to make the correct error message with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused that you are setting value for `ErrorMessage` with `string.Format(ErrorMessage ?? "", comparisonValue);`. `ErrorMessage` is the value from `[AmountShouldBeLessOrEqual(nameof(MaxAmount), ErrorMessage = "Your amount should be less than {0}")]` which you should not change during `IsValid`.

Try to define a scoped variable in `IsValid` to store the formatted error message.

```
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string error = "";

        var currentValue = (decimal)value;

        var comparisonValue = GetComparisonValue(_comparisonProperty, validationContext);

        if (ErrorMessage == null && ErrorMessageResourceName == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Amount is large";
        }
        else
        {
            error = string.Format(ErrorMessage ?? "", comparisonValue);
        }

        return currentValue >= comparisonValue
            ? new ValidationResult(error)
            : ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

Comment: The tip you have pointed was correct. I checked it. It works now... Thank you