# How to create a custom required if validator in asp.net core 2.1 or above

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations, customvalidator

How we can create a custom model validation with both client side and server side validation in asp.net core. My requirement is to check the value of a property and if it satisfies the value, the required field should be enabled. other wise disable.  The annotation can also be applied on object properties.Like this.

```
public class TradeModel
{   
    public bool TradingObjectives { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("TradingObjectives","true",ErrorMessage="required")]
    public int Hedge{ get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("TradingObjectives","true",ErrorMessage="required")]
    public AddressModel Address{ get; set; }

}

public class AddressModel 
{
    public long AddressId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to refer [How to reset the formatted ErrorMessages of the validation attributes in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636422/how-to-reset-the-formatted-errormessages-of-the-validation-attributes-in-asp-net/53645586#53645586)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) for custom validators. And you can add client-side support to Fluent Validation with [FormHelper](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/formhelper).

You can write custom validators, even database queries. It's an amazing solution for you.